# Purpose of runat="server" in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, runatserver

You use a `runat="server"` attribute everytime you want to access a html control (`div`,`span`,`H1`) from the server, you then also have to set it **everytime** you use an asp.net web control (`<asp:Button/>`).

My question is, for the asp.net web controls (all those beginning with `<asp:`) why haven't the asp.net team just removed it and set the property up in the background?

It makes no sense to have to set it every time, as there is no other option than `server`.

Is there is a point behind all of this, or an exception to the rule am I not aware of?

Comment: In theorie `asp:control` could be used client side only. But I agree with you that they are used 99% of time with `runat="server"`.

Comment: There is a runat="client" option too but I've never seen it used

Comment: @RickS How did you find that!? I searched everywhere :-( Thank you for pointing me to the answer! :)

Comment: GoogleFoo my child...